# Hypothesis testing and the size of critical region

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'm studying stats in order to obtain a certificate and I'm struggling with this question. I've searched a lot and I really didn't understand how to procede in this question. I even don't know how to begin to solve this question. Can someone help me? The fact that average is unknown is confusing me too, I don't know how to start in this way.

Let X1, X2, ..., Xn be a random sample of the Normal distribution with unknown average $\mu$ and variance equals to 1. A statistical test is being conduced and it wants to text H0: $\mu$ = $\mu0$ versus H1: $\mu$ $\ne$ $\mu0$. Suppose *n* = 16 and the critical region is in the form of | $\bar X$ - $\mu0$| $\ge$ *c*. What is the value of *c* such that the size of the test is 0,01?

Sorry for my English :~

Comment: Hint: what is the distribution of $\bar X$ if $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0,1)$?

Comment: $\bar X$ has a Normal distribution too. Can you explain further?

Comment: Ok. Can you derive the actual distribution of $\bar X$? If so, what is the probability that $|\bar X - \mu_0| \geq c$ for some $c > 0$? Is there a value for $c$ such that there is only a, say, 1% chance that it will be exceeded IF $X$ has mean $\mu_0$...do you see how this can help you assess if the $X$ were indeed generated by a normal distribution with mean $\mu_0$?